# Oracle SQL Developer complaining about java version missing

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm not able to run Oracle SQL Developer on my mac(macOS Big Sur)
It complains about the Java Version which is strange, because I have Java 11 installed, installed via `HomeBrew`, and idea what might be the issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but are you certain that you downloaded SQL Developer for MacOS? Also, I'm only guessing but SQL Developer may be looking for environment variable JAVA_HOME. Have you defined such a variable?

Comment: @Abra I have downloaded the right version for a Mac, but I have not set the `JAVA_HOME` env. that is worth the try, I will try that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4477413/sql-developer-on-macos-11-big-sur

Comment: @Abra that's a great link, I managed to start up the SQL-Developer with the command line script, I think my issue is I have two java versions. When I run this command `➜  ~ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home` this java version is only needed for the Data Loader, and is not in path.

Comment: this is what have in my `~/.zshrc` => `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: we use this to find the JDK /usr/libexec/java_home -- that needs to return a valid jdk home. You can manually tell sqldev where to find java by updating product.conf file in your $HOME/.sqldeveloper directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Developer on a Mac will look for a Java JDK Home a la -

```
Jeffreys-Mini:21.2 thatjeffsmith$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If the answer is anything older than 7, equal to 9 or 10, or just something other than a valid JDK, it won't start.

8 or 11 are officially supported. I've played with 14, 16, and GraalVM 16. Stay away from the GraalVM for SQL Developer today - it's got issues. The newer Java's should be OK, although you'll get a warning about running a version higher than officially supported (8,11).

If you've done all of this, and it STILL won't load. cd to your $HOME. Then go into your .sqldeveloper directory, and look for a a directory of the same name as your SQLDev version.

```
/Users/thatjeffsmith/.sqldeveloper/21.2.1
```

In there is a product.conf, find this line, uncomment it, supply full path to the JDK, save it, then start SQLDev.

```
#
# By default, the product launcher will search for a JDK to use, and if none
# can be found, it will ask for the location of a JDK and store its location
# in this file. If a particular JDK should be used instead, uncomment the
# line below and set the path to your preferred JDK.
#
# SetJavaHome /path/jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac M1, make sure you download the correct download for Mac ARM64.